# Is it possible to encode some data in a image and decode the data from hard copy?

Tags: encryption, encoding

I am working on a project which can encode some data in an Image and share it with other people by printing it out as hard copy. Now, other people can take a picture of the hard copy they got and decode the data.

I started researching on it and found some efficient projects like [Mobistego](http://mobistego.sourceforge.net/) which can encode and decode any image very effectively.

But the thing is, I wanted to use my Android phone's camera to take random shots and compare with a pre stored image and decode the data.

Other way possible can be like using some image recognition algorithm.

Comment: You can also look for **watermarking** different printers print nearly invisible watermarks to identify the source - there are furthermore nearly invisible digital watermarks on certain images on the net, to identify misuse - some of them can survive printing and rescanning

Comment: Well, while visual cryptography on printed sheet already seems to be a very narrow scope, visual cryptography on printed then photographed (using a common phone camera even more) seems very, very specific and I doubt there is any viable solution. However, you may want to get in touch with the people from [crypto.se] who may have better knowledge of uncommon cryptographic projects which may match your needs (maybe some stenography method which could survive the image being printed then photographed?).

Comment: Thanks @Falco and WhiteWinterWolf. I'll check and get back.

Comment: Some kind of an image with data? Like a QR code?

Comment: How much data are you trying to encode?  A few words, couple sentence, paragraphs, pages?  The low resolution of camera phones will limit your ability to encode large amounts of data.

Comment: @Aron Kinda yes, but the scanning should be done on complete image. Same as [LayAR](https://www.layar.com/).

Comment: @cybernard If possible, I need to store any smallest data to identify the image. A simple integer id is enough.

Comment: You want to generate a hash of the image like tineye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pastec.io](http://pastec.io/) is a very nice API using OpenCV, which can be used for encrypting the image and detecting using android phone's camera.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Visual cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_cryptography):

> Visual cryptography is a cryptographic technique which allows visual
>   information (pictures, text, etc.) to be encrypted in such a way that
>   decryption becomes a mechanical operation that does not require a
>   computer.

The method I know relies on using several printed pages to convey the message. Taken separately these pages will just contain blank noise, but if combined by using transparency then their mutual content visually combinate and the hidden picture appear.

I recommend you [this nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bb24mBADuG0), it visually shows the idea and then apply it into a watermarking system embedding a logo inside a black & white printed photo.